# How to play a flv video in html5

Tags: javascript, html, video, flash

i have a video player

```
<video id="myMovie">        
            <source src="vids/flv640x480/4fa2ab38f9237e9f2515812ee7fec1961d9c78d1.flv">
</video>
```

Now this video is not able to play in my browser chrome because its unsupported therefore i know flash is the way out but what do i need to do with flash. Install it on my server  or what ? 
Please anyone is there with a good explanation and steps of how to play flv videos  in any browser ?

Answer (score 0):

flv videos is not compatible with video tag

You have 2 options from here:

1.You use flash based video players (i.e. Flowplayer) or create your own

Here's a sample usage of flow player:

```
<!-- player container-->
<a href="http://yourwebsite.com/yourflvvideourlhere.flv"    class="player"
style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;margin:10px auto"
id="player">
</a>

// install flowplayer
$f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf");
```

1. Convert your video file to a format that is compatible with video tag (i.e. mp4, webm)

Comment: i dont wanna convert can u explain a bit about option 1 ?

Comment: here's a link how to install flow player with a minimal setup: http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/installation/index.html and this is how to use flow player with basic configuration: http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/index.html

Comment: i just need my videoplayer to be able to play flv files is that possible ? @maai

Comment: if you mean you want to convert your flash video to swf, you can simply embed it this way: <embed src="yourflashvideoplayer.swf" width="550" height="400" wmode="transparent" />

Comment: if you want to create a flashvideo player that can play multiple videos, here's a tutorial that may help you: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Create-an-Adobe-Flash-Video-Player/#step7