# Creating own flash video player

Tags: jquery, html, flash, flv, video-player

I want to create my **own** *flash video player*. Such that it supports flv video formats.
Can anyone guide me ? 
How do i start with creating a flash video player ?
I had an expereince of creating a ***html5 video player*** but don't know about flash.

**PS:** I dont want to use any plugins.

**Related to:** [How to play a flv video in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229110/how-to-play-a-flv-video-in-html5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gotta understand.. Making a video player in Flash is more like an intermediate skill not an overnight thing. Flash's coding language is ActionScript which is more like C++/C# instead of JavaScript (sometimes I only look at C-based examples for some of my multimedia coding and translate to Flash/AS3, that's how closely related grammar-wise they are).

Not to discourage you but saying this is what you're in for.. Basically in HTML they know you're mostly marking up how the page displays right? So a lot is taken care of for you behind the scenes by the browser coders, in Flash, for some things, you WILL be that coder.

You should read this before you begin..
- [How to make an AS3 Flash video player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985935/how-to-make-an-as3-flash-video-player)

**To Get Started:**

Download a trial (30 days) version of Flash :

- https://creative.adobe.com/products/flash

Get comfortable with the interface etc, Learn how to put code in a document class..

These two are the simplest tutorials I can recommend for a first timer..

- http://blog.martinlegris.com/2008/06/03/tutorial-playing-flv-video-in-plain-as3-part-1/
- http://www.codingcolor.com/as3/as-3-simple-video-player/

later on..

- http://republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xmlvideoplayer/